# how to display only a few sprites from a group at a time

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

i wanted to make a game start screen and wanted to show only a few buttons at a time from a group, but i did not want to create multiple groups for each screen as i think its not optimal.

i have currently used this, but it draws all buttons on all screens.

```
if screen_mode == 'main':
        buttons_group.draw(screen, [play_buttons, option_buttons])
elif screen_mode == 'options':
        buttons_group.draw(screen, [credit_buttons])
```

should i just create a new group for each screen_mode?

Comment: *"i did not want to create multiple groups for each screen as i think its not optimal."* - Why do you think so? This is the usual solution and I can't see any downside in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not solution using on single [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw). However, there are many other options. Here are a few of them:

1. Use multiple [`pygame.sprite.Group`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). Put the sprites you want to show into a group and draw only that group. There is no downside to this approach. The groups only contain a reference to the sprites.
2. Do not use `pygame.sprite.Group.draw`, but iterate through the sprites and `blit` only the sprites that meet a certain condition

   ```py
   for sprite in buttons_group.sprites():
       if sprite.evalaute_your_condition():
           screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect)
   ```
3. Use [`pygame.sprite.LayeredDirty`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredDirty) and [`pygame.sprite.DirtySprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.DirtySprite). `DirtySprite` have a `visible` attribute. With this attribute you can set the visibility of the sprite.